# SailsJs and custom route conflict

Tags: sails.js

I've developed a URL shortener for using internally using SailsJS. Everything is as expected but the issue is with custom route. I've written route this way

```
'/': "HomeController.index",
'/login/fb': "UsersController.FBlogin",
'/login/ggl': "UsersController.GGLlogin",
'/logout': "UsersController.logout",
'/*': "sController.redirect"
```

Now the issue is `domain/min/production.min.css` is being affected for the last route.

How I can disable that routing for assets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set `skipAssets: true` for the last route

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes and go to paragraph of `route-target-options` , unfortunately can't link it directly.